# Zend get page title in constructor

Tags: php, zend-framework, logging

I'm trying to store user activity in site: page title and url.

```
public function init(){
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

How to get title ?

Comment: What do you mean title?

Comment: @HerrSerker `<title></title>`

Comment: You don't get the title, you create it. Or do you mean, the title of the page, the user is comming from?

Comment: @HerrSerker mhm no I need curret page title, it's inpossible to get ?

Comment: you set title in layout. What you need?

Comment: Your question is not very well asked. Please be mor specific, what you are trying to do!

Comment: It is important for us to know how you set your page title so we can help you how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose i have controller

$this->headTitle($this->title);`

```
 class gusetcontroller extend abstractController{

public function gettitleAction() { return array('title'=>$title); }
}
$this->headTitle($this->title);
```